# "View" disapear when "padding" is removed

Tags: react-native

I am studying React Native and trying to understand the behavior of the components' style.

I am just creating a simple app and testing the padding style.

Why the boxes disapear when I remove the padding style?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.box} />
        <View style={styles.box} />
        <View style={styles.box} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  box: {
    padding:20, //remove this line
    margin: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'steelblue'
  }
});
```

Comment: Boxes have no height or width, so they simply don't have dimensions. Adding them a `padding: 20` is likely providing them a `width` and `height` of 40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause `<View />` is like `<div>` in HTML, it's size is determined by its content, if you remove the padding, then it occupies 0 space.

One way to keep `<View />` visible even if it has no content, is to set flex in style like { flex: 1  }

Answer (score 0):

The Box View needs to be either of **Fixed dimensions** like this:

```
box: {
    //width: 50,
    //height: 50,
    padding:20,
    margin: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'steelblue'
  }
```

By padding it is given a fixed size, but if you remove padding it will have no size.

Or you can use **Flex dimensions** like this:

```
box: {
    flex:1,
    padding:20,
    margin: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'steelblue'
  }
```

In this one you can safely remove `padding:20,` line.

Comment: I tried to remove the `padding` when `flex` was set to `1` and the boxes disappeared. But using the explanations given here, I could found the reason. In this case, `flex: 1` set the `height` but not the `width`, therefore it is necessary to keep `padding: 20` or include `width: 20` in order the boxes has width and are visible.